# Css Repeating Background

Tags: css, xhtml

So I have a background image for my content on a site and was wondering if there was a way to make the background repeat on the y axis when content starts to overflow. Here is what it looks like: http://ithacawebdesigners.com/temp_data/wildfirewp/

Thanks!

e. here is the div

```
#content {
float:left;
height:100%;
width:860px;
padding-top:10px;
background:url('http://ithacawebdesigners.com/temp_data/wildfirewp/images/contentbackw.png') repeat-y;
margin:0 0 0 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout.css file you have this block around line 260:

```
#content .page,#content .attachment,.postcontent {
height:500px;
width:720px;
margin-top:15px;
margin-left:30px;
float:left; 
}
```

Remove the `height` rule; it is limiting the height of your background. Unfortunately your background doesn't tile well, but this will get you started.

Comment: Nice! I forgot about that block. Damn you wordpress!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the fixed `height` (500px) from your `.postcontent` css class. Everything else seems to be in order.

Comment: Thanks brah, got it to tile. Now just need to create a background that actually looks good tiled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Comment: No need to downvote him. His response answered the question you framed.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-repeat.asp) to use **background-repeat:repeat-y;**
It should work

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS add:

```
background-repeat : repeat-y;
```